# Bootstrap: prevent button dropdown from getting cut off in table-responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a button link dropdown in a table row and the table is wrapped in table-responsive class. If you click the link as noted below, the dropdown is constrained within the table-responsive div and the vertical scrollbars appear. I want the dropdown to show just as if it would w/o the table-responsive div  wrapper.

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/tDIOZSwkn5) example. Click the last "mark as" link to see the issue.

Comment: ...@mdo stated: For the time being, we won't be supporting dropdowns within responsive tables (or anything else with an overflow on it). See issue and some ideas for work arounds: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11037

Comment: ahh.. thanks for the tip. Should make this an answer.

Comment: Here is one workaround__ http://bootply.com/0u7xDGGQeq

Comment: ya, but now the table is no longer responsive and won't scroll horizontal on small screen. I just used the `popup` class on the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the `popup` class on the last row.